# Add params to populate jeasy ui panel in ajax

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-easyui

I have a dialog (same as panel) to populate with data from server. I need to add parameters in the request. http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/panel.php

```
    var myparams = {type: mytype, section: mysection}
    $('#mydialog').dialog({
        title: mytitle,
        width: $(window).width()/3,
        closed: false,
        cache: false,
        href: href,
        queryParams: myparams,
        modal: true
    });
```

I tried to use the loader property and the queryParams property but both doesn't work !! Any ideas ?

Comment: yes, It works, but I want to add params as I said above.

Comment: yeah I only just saw this now - your `myparams` object is misformed. it should be  `{ type: mytype, section: mysection }`

Comment: I made the mistake only in stackoverflow not in my source code.

Comment: what version of easyui are you using? Also presuming `mytype` and `mysection` are variables?

Comment: yes, variables. I'm using the 1.3.6

Comment: is this of any use http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=1496.0

Comment: In the developers console is the queryParam data getting sent with the request? Are you handling the queryParams on the server side?

Comment: in the developers console,  I saw params are not sent with the request.

Comment: Just looking now - you linked to easyui panel but youre actually using easyui dialog. On the dialog page, http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/dialog.php, there is no mention of queryParams.

Comment: yes but dialog extends window and window extends panel. In the documentation you will see :`The properties extend from window, below is the overridden properties for dialog.`

Comment: Do mytype and mysection exist when dialog created? How are they gotten? have you tried testing with hardcoding params in the dialog option and checking if they are sent - instead of `queryParams: myparams` using `queryParams: { type: "test" }`?

Comment: Yes I tried to hardcoding params =/

Comment: Sorry man - Im out of ideas..